# IdentityServer4 w/AspNetIdentity and Registration API Methods

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I've setup IdentityServer4, a protected API (Core) project, and various clients. Anonymously accessed client pages use the Resource Owner flow to access the APIs and user credentials are used from client pages where login is required. This is all working. My problem is now I want to add registration API methods that are protected.

The new registration methods require the API project to use AspNetIdentity. Specifically they use Identity's UserManager object which is failing to instantiate unless I add this code to my Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

But adding this code breaks the normal IDServer4 Bearer authentication. The Authorize tag on the API controller now sends the requesters to the login page. Is there a way to create a good userManager component without the chunk of code above so Identity authentication does not come into play?

Without the code above I get the following error:

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[TestAPICore.Models.ApplicationUser]' while attempting to activate *controller*
```

Here is my ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ApiName = "api1";
            });

        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        }));

        //// ADDING THIS CAUSES API requests to send back the login screen
        //services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        //    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

Ideas for making this work?

**Update:**

Reading more, it looks like calling `services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(cfg => {});` is the way to go. I've tried it both before and after the `.AddAuthentication` code but I still get nearly the same error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[TestAPICore.Models.ApplicationUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[TestAPICore.Models.ApplicationUser]'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites...
```

...which is slightly different since it no longer references my controller.

**Solved!**

Here's what worked...

```
IdentityBuilder builder = services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options => { });
builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(IdentityRole), builder.Services);
builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Thanks,Kirk, for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Wait a second, are you trying to add ASP.NET Identity Core to an resource app (WebApi project)? ASP.NET Identity should be put on the same app which also hosts IdentityServer 4, if you want IdSrv4 to use ASP.NET Core Identity infrastructure for authentication

Comment: The docs [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html) explain how to implement Identity Core into IdSrv4

Comment: @Tseng: We don't want the APIs in the same project as the IdentityServer, no. We want them in a separate API site but protected by IdentityServer.

Comment: @Tseng: Our IdentityServer is already working fine with AspNetIdentity. Thanks for your response though.

Comment: But why do you want to register `services.AddIdentity<...>()` in your api Projects?? Asp.NET Core Identity is the whole thing (per application users). Maybe you're just looking for cookie authentication? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: @Kirk: Correct.

Comment: I'm getting the same error (Unable to resolve service...) when I replace .AddIdentity with this code: services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            });

Comment: According to this (https://chsakell.com/2018/04/28/asp-net-core-identity-series-getting-started/) I may have to build out the UserStore a bit. Working on it...:)

Comment: On that line of code, now I get Error: Application startup exception: System.ArgumentException: The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity of the generic type definition.
Parameter name: instantiation
   at System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions.AddStores(IServiceCollection services, Type userType, Type roleType, Type contextType)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that others may benefit, here's my whole ConfigureServices method for my API project which can manage users but still authenticates against IdentityServer:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                    options.ApiName = "api1";
                });

            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", bld =>
            {
                bld.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));

            // *** The Fix ***
            IdentityBuilder builder = services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options => { });
            builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(IdentityRole), builder.Services);
            builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

            services.AddMvc();
        }
```